# Dynamically adding content to HTML document using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create some dynamic content within a HTML document which contains nested PHP code, as follows:

```
$html=$DOCUMENT_ROOT. "test.php";
$page=new DOMDocument();
$page->loadHTMLFile($html);
...get existing elements by ID
...create new elements
...append new elements to existing elements
$page->saveHTMLFile($html);
```

The code raises a whole bunch of these warnings:

#### *DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in test.php*

Furthermore, it appears that the PHP tags

#### < ?PHP   ? >

within the source file were replaced with these:

#### <?php   ?&gt

and thereafter the nested PHP commands are not executed but instead only displayed in the output.

I'm assuming that the PHP load/save HTML file functions are not meant for PHP files, so how could we load and save PHP files?

Thank you for your help.

Sofia

Comment: Can you give more context of what you are talking about? Are you saying you want to load a HTML page and add content to it? Is this content on your site why would you not just add the HTML inside your template?

Comment: @wallerjake: Hi. To answer your question, yes. Specifically, I'm trying to populate a form with a number of checkboxes based on data retrieved from the database. And this data changes constantly.

Comment: Why are you not just adding that data inside your PHP template? Are you expecting it to automatically refresh or something? I would add the content directly inside of test.php

Comment: @wallerjake: Since it's not going to be a permanent state, the original HTML content will remain unchanged, and the checkboxes will be dynamically added based on the data from the database. The goal is not to save a new version of the page everytime it is viewed, but rather only display the current version with saveHTML instead of saveHTMLFile.

Comment: I think the answer below would work then right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you should `include("test.php")` and dynamically add the checkboxes in test.php to the form, something like this:

```
<?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
    <?php echo $option['label']?>: <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $option['name']?>" /><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still not able to successfully implement it, so I'm using a workaround through JavaScript.